# How to set padding or margin of element in code behind in Zebble for Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-zebble, zebble

I set it like code below, but it did not worked.

```
ProductList.Margin = 10 //Exception
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ProductList` is a `View` you can change its padding and margin like this:

```
ProductList.Css.Padding = 10;
ProductList.Css.Margin = 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use the extension methods which provide a fluent API (as they return the object back) like the following:

```
ProductList.Padding(10).Margin(20);
```

These extension methods allow you to set specific sides too. For example:

```
ProductList.Padding(top: 10, right: 15)
           .Margin(vertical: 20); // <-- this sets both top and bottom
```